# How to add a JavaScript event on change of field value in New CE form editor?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am aware of how to add event in classic Editor.

In the new CE Form Editor how do we add events to for example form or fields? I don't seem to find any relevant options.

Comment: actually that is really good question, I just went to one of my instance and tried to look for new UI but unfortunately I could not find a way to add event using new UI. You will have to switch to classic UI. I think Microsoft is still working on new UI and it's editor.

Comment: @AnkUser post it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is really good question, I just went to one of my instance and tried to look for new UI but unfortunately I could not find a way to add event using new UI.

You will have to switch to classic UI. I think Microsoft is still working on new UI and it's editor